# Lock screen while video keeps playing on second display

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, video, display

it seems impossible to me, but I was just wondering if it's possible to lock the screen (i.e. no one has access to my computer) while the second screen still displays a full-screen video.

By default, when I click `Super+L` both displays show my wallpaper with the box to enter my password. I would like this to stay on my main display (the laptop's) while the second display plays the video.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Seems impossible to me, but depending on the required safety, you *could* create something to prevent users to acces your system while playing a video. Not fit for completely unattended situations or smart offenders though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would look further into that. Anyway; would a guest account work for my usecase? say I won't lock the screen but with a guest account no one should have access to harmful data right?

Comment: Indeed a guest account does not have access to the `/home` directory of other users.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. If you want to post your comment as answer I  will be glad to accept it, since it solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, but you actually gave the answer yourself! You can post an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to create a guest account, and play the video from this account.